# Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, linux, ip-address

when I run my  program I get system crash "Segmentation fault" message.

I want to know if there is a way to know exactly the instruction (code line) that caused the system crash Segmentation fault message"

code ===>

```
#include "GeoIP.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char ipAddress[30];
    char expectedCountry[3];
    char expectedCountry3[4];
    const char *returnedCountry;
    GeoIP *gi;
    int failed = 0;
    int test_num = 1;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if (0 == i) {
            /* Read from filesystem, check for updated file */
            gi = GeoIP_open("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",
                            GEOIP_STANDARD | GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE);
        } else {
            /* Read from memory, faster but takes up more memory */
            gi = GeoIP_open("/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
        }

        if (gi == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening database\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* make sure GeoIP deals with invalid query gracefully */
        returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code_by_addr(gi, NULL);
        if (returnedCountry != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Invalid Query test failed, got non NULL, expected NULL\n");
            failed = 1;
        }

        returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code_by_name(gi, NULL);
        if (returnedCountry != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Invalid Query test failed, got non NULL, expected NULL\n");
            failed = 1;
        }

        f = fopen("/home/aa/test/country_test.txt", "r");

        while (fscanf(f, "%s%s%s", ipAddress, expectedCountry, expectedCountry3)
               != EOF) {
            returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code_by_addr(gi, ipAddress);
            if (returnedCountry == NULL
                || strcmp(returnedCountry, expectedCountry) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Test addr %d for %s failed, got %s, expected %s\n",
                        test_num, ipAddress, returnedCountry, expectedCountry);
                failed = 1;
            }
            returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code_by_name(gi, ipAddress);
            if (returnedCountry == NULL
                || strcmp(returnedCountry, expectedCountry) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Test name %d for %s failed, got %s, expected %s\n",
                        test_num, ipAddress, returnedCountry, expectedCountry);
                failed = 1;
            }
            returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code3_by_addr(gi, ipAddress);
            if (returnedCountry == NULL
                || strcmp(returnedCountry, expectedCountry3) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Test addr %d for %s failed, got %s, expected %s\n",
                        test_num, ipAddress, returnedCountry, expectedCountry);
                failed = 1;
            }
            returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code3_by_name(gi, ipAddress);
            if (returnedCountry == NULL
                || strcmp(returnedCountry, expectedCountry3) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Test name %d for %s failed, got %s, expected %s\n",
                        test_num, ipAddress, returnedCountry, expectedCountry);
                failed = 1;
            }
            test_num++;
        }
        fclose(f);

        f = fopen( "/home/aa/test/country_test2.txt", "r");
        while (fscanf(f, "%s%s", ipAddress, expectedCountry) != EOF) {
            returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code_by_addr(gi, ipAddress);
            if (returnedCountry == NULL
                || strcmp(returnedCountry, expectedCountry) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Test addr %d %s failed, got %s, expected %s\n",
                        test_num, ipAddress, returnedCountry, expectedCountry);
                failed = 1;
            }
            test_num++;
        }
        fclose(f);

        f = fopen( "/home/aa/test/country_test_name.txt", "r");
        while (fscanf(f, "%s%s", ipAddress, expectedCountry) != EOF) {
            returnedCountry = GeoIP_country_code_by_name(gi, ipAddress);
            if (returnedCountry == NULL
                || strcmp(returnedCountry, expectedCountry) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Test addr %d %s failed, got %s, expected %s\n",
                        test_num, ipAddress, returnedCountry, expectedCountry);
                failed = 1;
            }
            test_num++;
        }

        fclose(f);
        GeoIP_delete(gi);
    }
    return failed;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Use [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) for this.

Comment: Have you tried running your program through a debugger such as gdb?

Comment: Sure, compile with -g, then run with the debugger (`gdb myprogram`)

Comment: Yes, there is, run it in a debugger.

Comment: Quick guess: some `fopen()` call fails, returning a `NULL` file pointer which you then happily pass to `fread()`. I/O calls must be checked for success!

Comment: NULL check after fopen.

Comment: you may want to run `valgrind --leak-check=full --trace-origins myProg` to obtain more conclusive output

Comment: If you've got the answer your looking for, don't forget to "accept" it.

Comment: I don't yet receive the answer !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As many people stated: Use a debugger or a tool like `valgrind`.

However this might definitely be a source of problems (I've stripped non-interesting parts):

```
if (returnedCountry == NULL || ...) {
    fprintf(stderr, ".. %s ..\n", returnedCountry...);
    ...
}
```

There are several instances like this. You also have `fopen` calls where you don't check return value. **Always** do that.

Comment: Second that.  I've had segmentation faults from printf and co. before, due to slack NULL checks.  However, this if block checks for NULL then tries to print it anyway???

Answer (score 2):

add `-g` to your compile command line and then you're free to use `gdb./a.out` or `valgrind ./a.out`

(here `./a.out` is your program name)

Comment: `a.out` is the program name